# how to call a .net method from loadrunner script

Tags: .net, loadrunner

I have a loadrunner script, I need to invoke one of the .net method that is defined in my DLL. I have check lr_load_dll function but somehow it's not working.

Comment: see the concept of a function prototype.  You will need to add a function prototype for your remote call inside of your DLL

Comment: @JamesPulley can you share some article to quick start it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype.   You may fund numerous examples inside of the .h header files which are a part of the virtual users.  All of these functions are in support libraries (DLLs)

Comment: @JamesPulley I have checked this and understood the concept, But as I am new to .net and c++ both. I do not understand how to do it. Like I have a DLL that have someFunction how can I make it available in LR

Comment: Being conversant in the language if your tool is a foundation skill.  In this case C (not C++, not C#) is the default language of LoadRunner.  You may switch the language if you are more conversant in another language.  You also have the option of building a Visual Studio virtual user with your code.  See manual for more information

Answer (score 1):

What's your LR version? You can try the LR visual studio extension. You'll find the installation file in the Addition Components/IDE Add-Ins/LRVS2015IDEAddInSetup.exe

With this extension, you can create LR script in visual studio while using C# or C++. You can refer to this link. http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/WebHelp/Content/VuGen/164950_t_how_to_create_vuer_script_visual_basic_CSharp.htm